# Tough SQL Rank query

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, rank

Scenario: primary user table plus a separate audit table that tracks changes to the user's name.  Each time a user is added or part of their name is edited, we write a row to the audit table.

Trying to write a query that pulls the most immediate former name

```
select nsh.AuthEmail, nsh.UserID, nsh.name_lastnamefirst, t.FormerName, t.RankOrder
from (
Select 
    an.AuditNameID, nsh.AuthEmail, nsh.UserID, nsh.name_lastnamefirst, 
    FormerName = CASE WHEN RTRIM(an.LastName) <> RTRIM(nsh.LastName) OR RTRIM(an.FirstName) <> RTRIM(nsh.FirstName) OR RTRIM(an.Suffix) <> RTRIM(nsh.Suffix) OR RTRIM(an.MaidenName)<>RTRIM(nsh.MaidenName) THEN LTRIM(an.LastName + ' ' + an.Suffix + ', ' + an.FirstName + ' ' + ISNULL(an.MiddleName,''))
    ELSE null       
    END,
    RANK() over (partition by an.UserID order by an.AuditNameID DESC) RankOrder
From [dbo].[AuditName] an
INNER JOIN dbo.StudentPrograms p ON an.UserID = p.UserID 
INNER JOIN dbo.NameScalarHelper nsh ON p.UserID = nsh.UserID 
WHERE p.SiteProgramID = 139 AND p.IsActive =1 
) t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.NameScalarHelper nsh ON nsh.UserID = t.UserID
where FormerName is not null
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to return the data from audit table where the RANK is RANK -1 because the top rank is the current data.  Let me know if any ideas.

Comment: I didn't look into this too much, but I'm thinking your best bet would be `Lag`, perhaps - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Comment: please post expected result,actual result as text,it is hard to guess your requirement from your query

Comment: @JohnBustos It might not work if OP is using SQL Server 2008 R2 or older version.

Comment: You might as well do an inner join between t and nsh there - since you are then filtering by t.FormerName is not Null in the where clause. I believe it would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirement you basicly need to return latest name that doesn't match current one from your Audit table.

I think you could use `OUTER APPLY` to achieve that:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[StudentPrograms] AS SP
INNER JOIN [dbo].[NameScalarHelper] AS NSH
  ON NSH.UserID = SP.UserID
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM [dbo].[AuditName] AS AN
  WHERE AN.UserID = SP.UserID
    AND (
      RTRIM(AN.LastName) <> RTRIM(NSH.LastName)
      OR RTRIM(AN.FirstName) <> RTRIM(NSH.FirstName)
      OR RTRIM(AN.Suffix) <> RTRIM(NSH.Suffix)
      OR RTRIM(AN.MaidenName) <> RTRIM(NSH.MaidenName)
      )
  ORDER BY AuditNameID DESC
  ) AS AN
WHERE SP.SiteProgramID = 139
  AND SP.IsActive = 1;
```

This will find latest name from your audit table which doesn't match latest one.

By the way, I'd strongly suggest to clean up your database and remove any trailing/leading spaces, so that you don't need to use `LTRIM()` or `RTRIM()` in your where clause so that SQL Server would be able to make use of indexes. Read [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/) article for more details.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[StudentPrograms] AS SP
INNER JOIN [dbo].[NameScalarHelper] AS NSH
  ON NSH.UserID = SP.UserID
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM [dbo].[AuditName] AS AN
  WHERE AN.UserID = SP.UserID
    AND (
      AN.LastName <> NSH.LastName
      OR AN.FirstName <> NSH.FirstName
      OR AN.Suffix <> NSH.Suffix
      OR AN.MaidenNam) <> NSH.MaidenName
      )
  ORDER BY AuditNameID DESC
  ) AS AN
WHERE SP.SiteProgramID = 139
  AND SP.IsActive = 1;
```

I was trying to understand the way you store data and replicated a tiny example:

```
DECLARE @User TABLE
(
  UserID INT
  , FirstName VARCHAR(50)
  , LastName VARCHAR(50)
);

DECLARE @Audit TABLE
(
  AuditID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , UserID INT
  , FirstName VARCHAR(50)
  , LastName VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @User (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (1, 'Ben', 'White');

INSERT INTO @Audit (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (1, 'Ben', 'White');

SELECT *
FROM @User AS U
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM @Audit AS A
  WHERE A.UserID = U.UserID
    AND (
      A.FirstName <> U.FirstName
      OR A.LastName <> U.LastName
    )
  ORDER BY A.AuditID DESC
  ) AS A;

UPDATE U
SET U.LastName = 'Whiter'
FROM @User AS U
WHERE U.UserID = 1;

INSERT INTO @Audit (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (1, 'Ben', 'Whiter');

SELECT *
FROM @User AS U
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM @Audit AS A
  WHERE A.UserID = U.UserID
    AND (
      A.FirstName <> U.FirstName
      OR A.LastName <> U.LastName
    )
  ORDER BY A.AuditID DESC
  ) AS A;

UPDATE U
SET U.LastName = 'Whitest'
FROM @User AS U
WHERE U.UserID = 1;

INSERT INTO @Audit (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (1, 'Ben', 'Whitest');

SELECT *
FROM @User AS U
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM @Audit AS A
  WHERE A.UserID = U.UserID
    AND (
      A.FirstName <> U.FirstName
      OR A.LastName <> U.LastName
    )
  ORDER BY A.AuditID DESC
  ) AS A;

INSERT INTO @User (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (2, 'Tom', 'Brooks');

INSERT INTO @Audit (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (2, 'Tom', 'Brooks');

SELECT *
FROM @User AS U
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP (1) *
  FROM @Audit AS A
  WHERE A.UserID = U.UserID
    AND (
      A.FirstName <> U.FirstName
      OR A.LastName <> U.LastName
    )
  ORDER BY A.AuditID DESC
  ) AS A;
```

I assumed that when you create a user - you also add record to Audit table for consistency. Each time you make an update - you also log that into Audit table. Finally I just added yet another user and ran the query.

That's the output for each query:

User was created:

```
UserID FirstName LastName AuditID UserID FirstName LastName 
------ --------- -------- ------- ------ --------- -------- 
1      Ben       White    null    null   null      null
```

Its' last name was changed first time:

```
UserID FirstName LastName AuditID UserID FirstName LastName 
------ --------- -------- ------- ------ --------- -------- 
1      Ben       Whiter   1       1      Ben       White
```

Its' last name was changed second time:

```
UserID FirstName LastName AuditID UserID FirstName LastName 
------ --------- -------- ------- ------ --------- -------- 
1      Ben       Whitest  2       1      Ben       Whiter
```

A new user has been added:

```
UserID FirstName LastName AuditID UserID FirstName LastName 
------ --------- -------- ------- ------ --------- -------- 
1      Ben       Whitest  2       1      Ben       Whiter   
2      Tom       Brooks   null    null   null      null
```

Everything else is just formatting and you should not do  that in SQL Server - this should be done in application layer.

Comment: This answer is likely to be a more efficient method than using Rank().

Comment: The outer apply looks like it might be a winner - never used that before.  I will dig through it so I fully understand.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If this works for you, perhaps mark it as correct answer? Someone else might find it useful:)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your query, I'm guessing you are getting back all of a person's past names, since you have no filter based on the RankOrder that you've created. Your current name should be 1 in the RankOrder, I assume, and so your most recent previous name would be ranked 2. You can add this to your derived table's where clause like this:

```
    select nsh.AuthEmail, nsh.UserID, nsh.name_lastnamefirst, t.FormerName, t.RankOrder
from (
Select 
    an.AuditNameID, nsh.AuthEmail, nsh.UserID, nsh.name_lastnamefirst, 
    FormerName = CASE WHEN RTRIM(an.LastName) <> RTRIM(nsh.LastName) OR RTRIM(an.FirstName) <> RTRIM(nsh.FirstName) OR RTRIM(an.Suffix) <> RTRIM(nsh.Suffix) OR RTRIM(an.MaidenName)<>RTRIM(nsh.MaidenName) THEN LTRIM(an.LastName + ' ' + an.Suffix + ', ' + an.FirstName + ' ' + ISNULL(an.MiddleName,''))
    ELSE null       
    END,
    RANK() over (partition by an.UserID order by an.AuditNameID DESC) RankOrder
From [dbo].[AuditName] an
INNER JOIN dbo.StudentPrograms p ON an.UserID = p.UserID 
INNER JOIN dbo.NameScalarHelper nsh ON p.UserID = nsh.UserID 
WHERE p.SiteProgramID = 139 AND p.IsActive =1 and RankOrder = 2
) t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.NameScalarHelper nsh ON nsh.UserID = t.UserID
where FormerName is not null
```

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I think it will fail if there's just one name in audit table. Rank with `RankOrder = 2` will not exist and row will be excluded. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas You are correct, although I would not say that it "fails" in the sense of returning an error. I am making the assumption that having just one name in the audit table means that they do not have any past names, only a current one. The original query seems to be designed to exclude these records - the "where FormerName is not Null" seems to indicate that they only want records that have a past name. Overall, it is not clear to me what the requirements are from the question.

Comment: I agree, perhaps saying 'Fails' isn't correct in this case. Results probably wouldn't match A/C :)